# How to add an mp4 file to an existing rosbag?

Tags: python, ros, mp4

IN ROS using python
I can already save an mp4 video from a bag, but now I want to put one back

Comment: I want to put one back what!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [OpenCV video stream package](http://wiki.ros.org/video_stream_opencv). Then you can simply record the topic name via `rosbag record /some_video_topic`. Finally, you should use the [rosbag API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) to insert messages from your first bag into your existing bag.